# How to select a specific date range in a csv file with pandas (again)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I looked at the responses to this original question ([see here](http://How%20to%20select%20a%20specific%20date%20range%20in%20a%20csv%20file%20with%20pandas?) but doesn't seem to solve my issue.)

```
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader.data 
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(mypath + filename,  \
    skiprows=4,index_col=0,usecols=['Day', 'Cushing OK Crude Oil Future Contract 1  Dollars per Barrel'],  \
    skipfooter=0,engine='python')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 

ax.grid(axis='y',color='lightgrey', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
ax.grid(axis='x',color='lightgrey', linestyle='none', linewidth=0.5)

df['Cushing OK Crude Oil Future Contract 1  Dollars per 
Barrel'].plot(ax=ax,grid = True, \
color='blue',fontsize=14,legend=False) 

plt.show()
```

The graph turns out fine but I can't figure out a way to show only a certain date range.  I have tried everything.

```
type(df) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df.index) = pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

also, the format for the column `'Day'` is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a datetime index on your dataframe (it looks that way), you can slice using `.loc` like so:

```
% matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.rand(31)}, index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31'))

# Plot the entire dataframe.

data.plot()

# Plot a slice of the dataframe.

data.loc['2018-01-05':'2018-01-10', 'values'].plot(legend = False)
```

Gives:

[image]

The orange series is the slice.

Comment: Thank you.  That works with your example, but for some reason with mine it plots a separate graph below it with the slice of the data

Comment: That's OK though right? The point of this was to show how to slice a dataframe with a datetime index. Does that bit work for you?

Comment: Yes, that was basically what I was looking for, can figure out the rest. thanks. s